# Issue with image visibility in WPF - not showing when button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm developing a WPF application in C# where I have a button that should toggle the visibility of an image. I've followed the instructions and implemented the following code to handle the button click:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ROBOT_01.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="RobotHeadImage" Source="images/robot_head.png" Width="100" Height="100" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <Button Content="Toggle Image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20" Click="ToggleButton_Click" Width="100" Height="30"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace ROBOT_01
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private const Visibility HiddenVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        private const Visibility VisibleVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (RobotHeadImage.Visibility == VisibleVisibility)
            {
                RobotHeadImage.Visibility = HiddenVisibility;
            }
            else
            {
                RobotHeadImage.Visibility = VisibleVisibility;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that the image path is correct, set "Copy to Output Directory" for the image, and used the recommended code for visibility management.

Despite all this, when I press the button, the image doesn't appear or disappear as expected. I've tried searching for solutions online and followed the given instructions, but the issue persists.

Is there something I might be missing or an error I'm not detecting? Has anyone encountered a similar issue and can give me a hand in resolving it? Please help me understand what could be wrong.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or assistance!

Comment: May I ask why you have defined `const HiddenVisibility` and `VisibleVisibility` instead of using `Visibility.Hidden/Visible` directly?

Comment: Where are you wiring-up `void Button()`? Show your XAML. Have you used your debugger? If not, **why not**?

Comment: If you set the image to Visible in your XAML file does it display? If this does not happen, you should concentrate on getting it to display when your application starts before worrying about whether you can hide it when you click on the button.

Comment: You would usually not set `Copy to Output Directory` for an image file that is part of your Visual Studio project. Set the `Build Action` to `Resource` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy`. Make sure to load the image from a valid path relative to the assembly in which it is contained. If the file is for example located in a folder named `Images` in your project, load it like `<Image Source="/Images/ImageFileName.png"/>`

Comment: I also think you should try starting with your image visible. Then iterate from there. Add a togglebutton and bind visibility of your image with a boolean visibility converter to  ischecked of the togglebutton.

Comment: Please show your xaml. Did you try to put a breakpoint in the Button method?

Comment: How do i show my xaml code? Do i need to make a new post?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76927802/edit) the question.

Comment: Remove `Visibility="Hidden"` from the Image in XAML. Is it visible? If not, `images/robot_head.png` is not a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’ve copy-pasted things correctly, there’s an error in the way you subscribe to the click event.

The XAML for the button has this attribute: `Click="ToggleButton_Click"`

However, the C# code for the handler has this: `private void Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Rename the C# method into `void ToggleButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )` and your code will probably work.

P.S. If you use Visual Studio IDE, while debugging a WPF app the IDE provides live debugger for the WPF’s visual tree. You can inspect your visual tree, and properties of the elements on that tree. When debugging GUI issues like that, sometimes [that feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2022) helps substantially.

Comment: OP had asked this question a [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76955597/1136211), where they had ToggleButton_Click in the code behind. I have edited this question accordingly.